# CakePHP: Adding meta nofollow tag to layout from view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to be able to add a meta tag from a view (or controller if possible) in CakePHP

I have a page like `/mycontroller/myview` but when it is accessed with filters like:

`/mycontroller/myview/page:2/max_price:500`

Then I want to add meta no follow tags.

There is a *[meta](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/html-helper#method-HtmlHelpermeta)* method on the HtmlHelper class.

When I call it like this:

```
$this->Html->meta('keywords', 'test test test', array('inline'=>false));
```

It creates a meta tag like this:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="test test test" />
```

However, when I call it like this:

```
$this->Html->meta('robots', 'noindex, nofollow', array('inline'=>false));
```

I would naturally expect and ***want*** it to create this:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
```

Instead I get this though:

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/mycontroller/noindex, nofollow" type="application/rss+xml" rel="alternate" title="robots" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation page](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1438/meta) (last line)

> If you want to add a custom meta tag then the first parameter should be set to an array. To output a robots noindex tag use the following code:

```
echo $this->Html->meta(array('name' => 'robots', 'content' => 'noindex'));
```

In your case:

```
echo $this->Html->meta(array('name' => 'robots', 'content' => 'noindex, nofollow'),null,array('inline'=>false));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. :) BTW I see everyone always still uses echo when inline is false which doesn't actually echo anything, and still works when you just call it without the echo. I have not been using echo when the element is not inline, is there any reason to? I only ask because I see many do.

Comment: =P you're right, you shouldn't do an echo if the element is not inline.. It doesn't change anything, it's just a bad habit that i have.. srry

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tweaked version of the code from [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html?highlight=meta#HtmlHelper::meta). I've tested it, and it does work:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->meta(
    array('name' => 'robots', 'content' => 'noindex, nofollow'),
    null,
    array('inline'=>false));
?>
```

Obviously you can write this in a single line -I just broke it down for ease of viewing here.

Comment: +1 thanks, your and pleasedontbelong are both correct but I can only accept one.

Comment: you should echo this one

Answer (score 1):

You can set variables from the view to the layout in the same way you set from controller to view using `$this->set()`, I would have a setup like this:

```
// View
if($condition) {
    $this->set('nofollow', true);
}

// Layout (in <head>)
if(isset($nofollow) && $nofollow) {
    echo $this->Html->meta(array('name' => 'robots', 'content' => 'noindex, nofollow'));

}
```

Now you have a short 1-liner to add the nofollow directive from any view file.